# How can I optimize a Cassandra queue-like column family?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have a queue-like column family which updates frequently around every hour. After a couple of hours or a day cassandra has a lot of read time outs.

I have tried this but haven't gotten the result yet: gc_grace_seconds = 0 and using LeveledCompaction.

Or would you recommend the datetieredcompactionstrategy or is there another better strategy then these two?

If I cannot solve this I am thinking switching to another database do you think that is necessary?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: can you describe a bit more your data with some example. I am not sure I get what is a queue like column family

Comment: queue-like datasets http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets

Comment: I haven't load the page yet but in the title it says anti-pattern so I guess it isn't good

Comment: your article doesn't really help me understand what you did so if you could explain data structure and so on it would help greatly

Answer (score 1):

What your doing is an [anti-pattern](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets) and has a lot of issues tied to it which is important to point out.

That said you really want to keep your tombstones under control, as you get more and more cause a lot of GC issues and increase read latencies (has to read a lot of data off disk to read the empty queue). You are probably not getting the benefit of your gc_grace setting of zero due to the default `tombstone_compaction_interval`.

I would suggest you update your [compaction strategy](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/compactSubprop.html) to help:

```
ALTER TABLE footable WITH
  compaction = {'class': 'LeveledCompactionStrategy', 
    'sstable_size_in_mb': '256mb',
    'tombstone_compaction_interval': '1',
    'unchecked_tombstone_compaction': 'true',
    'tombstone_threshold': '0.05'} AND 
  gc_grace_seconds = 0
```

Keep in mind that more aggressive tombstone removal creates a possibility for a delete to be "lost". Really, if possible, you should look into updating your application to use something more suitable.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. What would you think is a more suitable solution for example?

Comment: akka, kafka, rabbitmq, it really depends on your usecase and what rest of your dev/ops team are comfortable with.

Comment: My job queue is not a FIFO queue, each job has a due time. Therefore I want to start the job at the correct time. What do you think is suitable for this task? Coudln't find kafka, akka or abbitqm supporting this but maybe there is a solution. Thanks

Comment: I also think that even when using Kafka the same problem might occur there.